# QFT and Hamiltonian relativistic mechanics rigorous books

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism, second-quantization, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Where can I find a good and rigorous reference on QFT and second quantization? It seems I would also require references on Hamiltonian relativistic field theory and on distribution theory on manifold, to treat second quantization properly I suppose.